# Unable to catch error in laravel using try catch

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I wrote a code to try and catch error.

I want that if the error occurs then laravel continues to the next one and i write the error in the error file as shown here.

Laravel's black page of error pops up which shows "ErrorException (E_WARNING) followed by the whole error on the left page and the programme is abruptly stopped.
Is there a way to skip the error notification which brings my whole code to a stop.

My attempt at coding to catch the error is here:

```
try {
    $jsondata_car = (file_get_contents($urltofind_car));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errorfile = fopen("errors", 'a');
    fwrite($errorfile, $e - > getmessage().
        "\n");
    $failed_car = 9999999;
    report($e);
    return false;
}
```

Am I missing out something? 
The error I get is here

> file_get_contents(): failed to open stream:
>   HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

The error is shown on the line

```
    $jsondata_car = (file_get_contents($urltofind_car));
```

**The solution is here**

Exception is used which should have contained a namespace.

The problem is that this does not throw up an error even though I had not written

> Use Exception;

at the beginning.

As suggested by @simon R I made the rectification and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely still throwing the error because you haven't imported the Exception class

Ensure you either add

`Use Exception;`

to your class.

Alternative update your code to namespace it;

```
try {
    $jsondata_car = (file_get_contents($urltofind_car));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $errorfile = fopen("errors", 'a');
    fwrite($errorfile, $e - > getmessage().
        "\n");
    $failed_car = 9999999;
    report($e);
    return false;
}
```